# PostgreSQL - JSON function

Tags: postgresql

There's a different format for `row_to_json` and `json_build_object`.

For `row_to_json` the input is:

```
select ...  <table.field>   "<json_key"
```

And for the `json_build_object`:

```
 "<json_key" , <table.field>
```

That's surprising to me. Oracle uses similar JSON functions with similar input. This may look like a minor thing, but it makes it harder for me to automate the generation of `SELECT` statements for complex/nested structures.

Consider this simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    email_address VARCHAR(150),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
  );

 INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "name", "email_address")
  VALUES (1, 'user1', 'user1@mail.com'), (2, 'user2', 'user2@mail.com');
```

To fetch the email and the name where email is a dictionary object:

```
"{""user_name"":""user1"",""email"":{""email_address"" : ""user1@mail.com""}}"
```

The query would be:

```
select row_to_json(users) from 
(select users.name "user_name" ,
 (json_build_object(  'email_address' , users.email_address )) email
  from users ) users;
```

I would like to use the same order of fields in both cases.
The input would be:

```
<table.field> "<json_key" OR  "<json_key" <table.field>
```

I tried to flip the order using "AS" but it doesn't work:

```
select row_to_json(users) from 
(select users.name "user_name" ,
 (json_build_object(   users.email_address  as 'email_address' )) email
  from users ) users;
```

Maybe with using *only* `row_to_json()` or `json_build_object()`?
Or anything else? (But no `left join`.)

Comment: If they had the same input format, they would be the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`row_to_json` takes an entire row tuple (a record) as input, such as you get it from a subquery. If you don't use those, or don't like `row_to_json`, don't use it. It's a convenience mainly if you use `SELECT *` and not want to specify column/field names.

I recommend to use `json_build_object` with explicit field names, especially if you want to rename them anyway. Your query can and should be written as

```
SELECT json_build_object(
  'user_name', users.name,
  'email', json_build_object(
    'email_address', users.email_address
  )
) AS json_result
FROM users;
```